# Custom Item Resolver not setting context item

Tags: mvc

I have a custom item resolver where I am trying to set the context item based on the path in the url (this is for a re-written url). I've patched this in after Sitecores ItemResolver and it runs fine. However when my page loads the context item doesn't seem to be set correctly when I attached the debugger and none of my renderings get the correct item. It  looks similar to this:

```
   public class CustomUrlResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
   {
      public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
      {
         Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

         /*In Case Sitecore has mapped the item, do not do anything and simply return*/
         if (Context.Item != null || Context.Database == null || args.Url.ItemPath.Length == 0) return;

         /*If not, Check for item based on the FilePath*/
         Item contextItem = CustomUrlManager.GetItemByFilePath(args.Url.FilePath);
         if (contextItem != null) Context.Item = contextItem;
      }
   }
```

As a test I tried to see if I could set the context item in one of my controller renderings and I can force the context item like so:

```
Item contextItem = CustomUrlManager.GetItemByFilePath("/a-path/my-item", Context.Database);
if (contextItem != null)
{
    Context.Item = contextItem;
    rc.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item = contextItem;
    rc.RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem = contextItem;
    rc.RenderingContext.Current.PageContext.Item = contextItem;
}
```

Other components further down the page then pick up the correct context item  However it doesn't seem to work correctly from a httpRequestBegin Pipeline.

I've tried moving when my pipeline executes and also removing any other custom Pipelines we have but can't seem to get the context item to be set correctly.

I am not sure if it's because we are using MVC and Glass and there is something I'm missing here but any ideas would be welcome?

**Other info:** Sitecore 8.1 update 2, MVC, Glass, url rewrite module: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Url_Rewrite.aspx

Comment: From what I remember, one of the mvc processors overrides `Sitecore.Context.Item`.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I'm guessing maybe SetupPageContext or GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext / GetFromRouteUrl. I'll do some more digging and see. If you remember which one though please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Pipeline that you want to focus in on is the **mvc.getPageItem** pipeline.

```xml
<mvc.getPageItem patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config">
  <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.SetLanguage, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteValue, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteUrl, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.PageLevelTestVariantResolver, Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.ContentTestVariantResolver, Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.config"/>
</mvc.getPageItem>
```

The processor **GetFromOldContext** will set the PageItem to `Context.Item` only if the previous processors haven't already identified an item.

```
  public class GetFromOldContext : GetPageItemProcessor
  {
    public override void Process(GetPageItemArgs args)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
      if (args.Result != null)
        return;
      args.Result = this.ResolveItem(args);
    }

    protected virtual Item ResolveItem(GetPageItemArgs args)
    {
      return Context.Item;
    }
  }
```

### Recommedation

Create a processor for this pipeline that comes after either **GetFromRouteUrl** or **GetFromOldContext** to determine whether you want to continue using the Page Item found, or use from the Custom Item Resolver.

### PageContext Does Overwrite Context.Item

A little more digging found that the `PageContext` has a Property for **Item**. When the `PageContext.Item` is fetched for the first time, it calls a method `GetItem()` which ends up calling the **mvc.getPageItem** pipeline.

If the ID of the `Context.Item` doesn't match the ID returned from this pipeline, then it resets the value of `Context.Item` to that of the Result from the pipeline.

```
protected virtual Item GetItem()
{
  using (new RecursionPreventer("GetItem", this.getItemFlag))
  {
    using (TraceBlock.Start("Get item for {0}.".FormatWith((object) typeof (PageContext))))
    {
      Item obj = PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<GetPageItemArgs, Item>("mvc.getPageItem", new GetPageItemArgs(), (Func<GetPageItemArgs, Item>) (args => args.Result));
      if (obj != null)
      {
        if (Context.Language == (Language) null || Context.Language != obj.Language)
          Context.Language = obj.Language;
        if (Context.Item == null || Context.Item.ID != obj.ID)
          Context.Item = obj;
        return obj;
      }
      Tracer.Info((object) "Using Sitecore.Context.Item.");
      return Context.Item;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks Pete! I've had a play around with this and nearly have it all working now. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 2):

If httpRequestBegin pipeline is base place where you are resolving the item, you can also re-patch the configuration and move GetFromOldContext to the first position

```
<mvc.getPageItem>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext, Sitecore.Mvc">
    <patch:delete />
  </processor>
  <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.SetLanguage, Sitecore.Mvc']" type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
</mvc.getPageItem>
```